# Is it possible to change shutter speed in Nikon D3300 remotely?

Tags: hdr, remote, nikon-d3300

I have Nikon D3300 camera that has no built-in HDR feature.

Anyway I would like to do some HDR photography.

My question is: is there any way to change the shutter speed in Nikon D3300 remotely (without touching the camera).

If so, what kind of remote control would work (manufacturer/model)?

Comment: Easiest solution would be to use exposure bracketing.  A quick search indicates that's not a feature of the D3300 either?  With bracketing you could set to aperture priority, bracket 3 shots, use the self timer set to do 3 shots (or use a remote shutter release) and it would adjust shutter speed after each shot.

Answer (score 1):

You can connect the wireless mobile adapter WU-1a to your camera and use your cellphone to control it.

Alternatively you can connect your camera to a computer for tethered shooting. The USB cable should be supplied with your camera. Nikon offers a program for that, but it is extremely expensive, while Canon offers theirs for free. I tested a free program called Sofortbild about 2 years ago, and it worked without problems on a Macbook air with a D7000.

Comment: And with a bit of technical know-how and effort it's possible to take the second suggestion and simulate the first. Various people have used a Raspberry Pi (and I think some even an Arduino) connected by USB to the camera and controlled remotely.

Answer (score -5):

You could turn on the "Active D-Lighting" feature in the setting to boost the dynamic range a bit.

Comment: This doesn't seem to answer the question.

Comment: @PhilipKendall It appears to be a suggestion for increasing apparent dynamic range, since the original question says that reason they want to change the shutter speed is for HDR. Va Hid, this isn't a discussion forum and doesn't work that way; answers in this section should actually be about what was asked.